# What is the relationship between WordPress pagebuilder and themes?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to understand the relationship between WordPress (default), a theme e.g. Astra or OceanWP, and a page builder e.g. Elementor or Divi?  In particular, with regards to widgets.

WordPress comes with a built-in page editor, a default theme and some widgets, e.g. text editor, blog posts. I believe the theme defines where the widgets can go, e.g. in footer, header or sidebars.

But I am confused by the fact that themes (like Astra) and page builders (like Elementor) both seem to provide widgets.  Is this correct?  I would have thought a page builder would just use widgets from theme?

I am trying to understand if there is overlap in what is provided by WordPress by default, in a theme, and with a page builder, and how they inter-relate. I would be most grateful if someone could please explain.

Thanks,
Ashley.

Comment: Page Builders introduce their own version of "sidebars". They're not the same sidebars defined in a traditional WordPress theme. PB have to resort to some tricks to "import" regular widgets (eg. Recent Posts) into their system. That's why you'll find that sometimes some more complex widgets won't completely work with Page Builders. This is one of the things Gutenberg & WordPress 5.x is trying to resolve.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56322397/how-does-my-completely-blank-wordpress-theme-works)