# How does my completely blank Wordpress theme works?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

I made a test. i have a Wordpress site using Elementor page builder (pages, archives, header, footer... everything made with Elementor page builder).

Now i made a theme which contains only two files:

```
index.php
style.css
```

The `index.php` file is completely blank. nothing inside it.
The `style.css` file contains the basic theme config comment thing.

Everything works great on the site. and my question is why?

For example how does the head part adds the used plugins if the theme doesn't contain wp_head() any where?

**Also (Second Question)** - what am i missing? where would this completely blank theme will fail?

Comment: Elementor will replace the entire `header.php` and `footer.php` incase if they exists and if they don't exists it will create a one and the head parts get injected using the  `wp_head` and `wp_footer` action hooks. Elemetor also use there premade header template

Comment: See the reference: https://elementor.com/blog/header-footer-builder/

Comment: I added a header.php file with "asdf" text, and still everything works the same?!

Comment: Yes that is it. Because elementor override the header and footer if yoo create using Elementor. try to remove header and footer section created by elementor and then check

Comment: So elementor replaces the sites header even if the template has a header file..

Comment: Yes that what i understand from there official site that i have come across